# Navbar icon text missing on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, navbar

i just want to ask what will be the best approach for my navbar. I manage to make my nav bar turn into icons on the left whenever i click on the toggle button. but when I suddenly enlarge my screen while the icons on the left is visible , my navbar returns to normal on the top but missing the label just the icons only.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">D.N.A <span>Builders</span></a></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> About</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Services</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Skills</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Teams</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

js:

```
   $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
   $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
   $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");
   })

   });


   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menu-btn").click(function(){
   $(".menu span").toggle();
   });

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you applied the active class on button's click event, try doing this at window's resize one.

Or, if you want to use bootstrap utilities, use its Grid system layout: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: thanks for that. but do you have the proper approach for windows resize js?

Comment: Of course, take a look in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rho1jzp/